# How to debug why a Kubernetes pod terminated

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

My setup works in my local Minikube. But at the GCE the Traefik controller terminates around half a minute after starting successfully  (`Started container with docker id xxx`, `traefik-ingress-controller-d8jb6   1/1       Running`).
While the pods run I don't get any new events from `kubectl describe pod --selector=k8s-app=traefik-ingress-lb --namespace=kube-system`. But as I cannot follow the `describe` command with `-f` like I can follow the `logs` command I don't know if any new event popped up short before pod termination that describes the error.

BTW: The GCE still uses Kubernetes 1.5.7.

In the Minikube as well as at the GCE the Ingress seems to find the Service as I see the following log output in the container:

```
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider kubernetes: {"backends":{"www.sandroboehme.de/":{"servers":{"web-deployment-439093506-08dk8":{"url":"http://10.0.0.4:8080","weight":1}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"wrr"}}},"frontends":{"www.sandroboehme.de/":{"entryPoints":["http"],"backend":"www.sandroboehme.de/","routes":{"/":{"rule":"PathPrefix:/"},"www.sandroboehme.de":{"rule":"Host:www.sandroboehme.de"}},"passHostHeader":true,"priority":1,"basicAuth":[]}}}" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Last kubernetes config received more than 2s, OK" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating frontend www.sandroboehme.de/" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend www.sandroboehme.de/ to entryPoint http" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating route / PathPrefix:/" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating route www.sandroboehme.de Host:www.sandroboehme.de" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend www.sandroboehme.de/" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=debug msg="Creating server web-deployment-439093506-08dk8 at http://10.0.0.4:8080 with weight 1" 
time="2017-06-01T11:57:56Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
```

But in the GCE case the last log messages are the following:

```
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=info msg="I have to go... terminated" 
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=info msg="Stopping server" 
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 10s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint http..." 
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint http closed" 
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=info msg="Server stopped" 
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=info msg="Shutting down" 
time="2017-06-01T10:14:50Z" level=error msg="Error creating server: http: Server closed"
```

How can I debug that to find out what causes the pod termination?

The complete yaml files can be found at the GitHub account https://github.com/sandroboehme/sling-gce-k8s-launchpad/tree/traefik/src/main/k8s the `single-mongo` folder is not relevant in this case. Please make sure to use the googlecloud_hdd.yaml only in the GCE case and remove the `storage-class: "slow"` only in the Minikube case.
Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!